# hadoop fs -cat and hadoop fs -text to count the file length , but the result is not equal

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

[image]I want to count the line of a hdfs file,so I use

`hadoop fs -cat /path/part-00982.lzo_deflate |wc -l` ,the result is 311424.

while I use

`hadoop fs -text /path/part-00982.lzo_deflate |wc -l` , the result is 2099305.

Why the same file,but two totally different result?Is there any defference between `cat` and `text`?

Comment: You can look at the output of the two commands without the `|wc -l` and see what the difference is.

Comment: -text shows normal result,but -cat  shows very strange characters.

Comment: Yes, so `text` is decompressing the file whereas `cat` is just displaying the bytes of the compressed file.